# Should we answer question about commercial products?

Tags: discussion, answers

It is the first time when I am in a situation like this. Somebody posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834218/image-responsive-not-working) about a website he/she has to create. The code was incomplete for us to give an answer, so I asked him/her in a comment to post the relevant code. I found out that the OP's question is about a commercial project (which you can see in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834218/image-responsive-not-working?noredirect=1#comment36673303_23834218)).

Should we freely answer questions with commercial purposes?

Comment: I know that almost every user here asks for commercial purposes, but when they do not post the needed code? Should I simply get away?

Comment: If the offtopic "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" close reason fits, use it. Makes no difference if the asker is doing business or homework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether the question is about a commercial product or not doesn't matter. As long as the OP fails at providing the relevant code required to solve its problem, you can:

- Leave a comment asking for the OP to post the code,

and/or

- vote to close.

I am not aware of anyone around here having a working crystal ball, it is the responsibility of the OP to provide relevant code while not infringing the rules of their company, possibly by adapting it.

Comment: downvoting might also be appropriate in that situation...

Answer (score 5):

This is right from the about

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Last time I checked commercial endeavors fall into the `every` category. In your case it sounds like the question was not appropriate for SO because it was unanswerable. If they can't provide enough details to answer then it should be closed as `off-topic` preferably with a comment explaining why.